# Facebook user similarity?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication, recommendation-engine

I am trying to build a Recommendation system that could use the information from facebook. Well on the process I am trying to find the similarity between a user and his friends. That way I could consider only n similar friends information as a training data set, instead of all the friends. So I would appreciate some suggestions regarding the features from facebook which could be used as measure of similarity. One such feature would be, say age. Friends within same age group would be similar.

Comment: i would first do the most obvious socially related.  Likes, Interests, Movies, TV, Books, -  
then move to age, gender, local, birthday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

---

- 1.
  A Facebook sdk or cURL can be used in conjuntion with an app id to query the information needed from Graph api.

Refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/

---

- 2.
  Permission will be needed, from user to app.

Refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

---

- 3.
  Access tokens will be needed in addition to permission

Refer to: "link above" & https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/

---

- 4.
  The user friends connection is the array you will need to do your comparisons with.

Refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#friends

---

Comment: can you tell whether you can find out activity between friends using the facebook API?

Comment: you can, you just need all the friends permissions to get that data.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use, same school/college, gender, sexual orientations, pages liked, groups... Don't know what you can access from FB API though, you might need an App or take a look at OpenGraph